# How to add image in a button?

Tags: javafx

I'am trying to add the image (icon.jpg) in the reset button. But its not loading on the button. I used the code written below. But its not working.

```
public StatusBar(){
    statusBarGp = new GridPane();

    File imagefile=new File("file:///C:/Users/Avi/Desktop/icon.jpg");
    Image icon_image=new Image(imagefile.toURI().toString());

    resetButton = new Button("",new ImageView(icon_image));

    whitePlayerAlert = new Label("");
    blackPlayerAlert = new Label("");
    whitePlayerTimer = new Label("");
    blackPlayerTimer = new Label("");
    Alert=new Label("");
    Alert1=new Label("");
    winner = new Label("");
    resetButton.setMaxSize(500.0, 200.0);

    resetButton.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 10, 10, 10, 10; ");

    //statusBarGp.setGridLinesVisible(true);

    statusBarGp.setSnapToPixel(false);
    statusBarGp.setEffect(new DropShadow());


    getChildren().add(statusBarGp);
}
```

Comment: What is exactly happening when it's not working?

Comment: its showing nothing.just a button with empty text.

Comment: Afaik `File` does not accept an URL, but a file path. The protocol is certainly not allowed in a file path and certain things may also be different. E.g. in an URL the a whitespace needs to be encoded as `%20`. (Doesn't seem to be the case here though.)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you're making the process much more complicated than it needs to be. The `ImageView` constructor accepts a `URL` for a parameter and you can pass the path to your image directly to it:

```
resetButton = new Button(null, new ImageView("file:///C:/Users/Avi/Desktop/icon.jpg"));
```

If that still results in an empty `Button`, confirm the image exists in the location you're entering.